# Checkbox from ComboBoxItem is binded to Boolean in Class. How to get every Boolean from every single Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, combobox

Sorry for my lacking of English and take in mind I just startet with WPF, so it might not even be the prettiest way to do this.

**I tried to remove every Item where the Checkbox is Checked but I have Problems to point toward the Checkbox. So I tried to point toward a Boolean within a Class. But there are also Problems. Then I surrendered and came here.**

**Any Help is appreciated.**

My Button who should delete a certain Item, with a checked checkbox, from a list looks like this.

```
private void DeleteComboBoxItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ComboBoxName.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ComboBoxName.Item.Contains((CheckBox).Equals(True))) <--- Have Problems here.
                {
                    List.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Only the Name of the Cat is within the List - I have a formula where I can add cat names.

I have a ComboBox with the following template:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxName">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding b_CheckBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding tb_Name}" />
                </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And a class that looks something like that.

```
public class Cat 
{
public bool b_Checkbox {get; set;}
public string tb_Name {get; set;}
}
```

**Hope you can Help me.**

Answer (score 0):

You want the checkbox to trigger a removal of the cat right? Dunno if this is the most efficient way but, it works

1. add an event each time the bool property in your Cat class changes:

   ```
    public class Cat 
    {

        public event Action<bool> CheckboxChanged;

        private bool imChecked;
        public bool ImChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return imChecked;
            }
            set
            {
                imChecked = value;
                CheckboxChanged?.Invoke(value);
            }
        }


        public string tb_Name { get; set; }            
    }
   ```
2. set up in you ViewModel the action you want to execute each time this event fires

```
 //In the constructor of your ViewModel, iterate through each cat and subscribe to its event. Then, give the cats to the comboBox
 public YourViewModel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            //Getting the cats
            ObservableCollection<Cat> Cats = new ObservableCollection<Cat>
            {
                new Cat () {tb_Name = "1st cat", ImChecked = false},
                new Cat () {tb_Name = "2nd cat", ImChecked = false},
                new Cat () {tb_Name = "3rd cat", ImChecked = false},
                new Cat () {tb_Name = "4th cat", ImChecked = false},
            };

           //Subscribing to each cat's event
            foreach (Cat cat in Cats)
            {
                cat.CheckboxChanged += CatChanged;
            }

            //Give the comboBox the cats
            YourComboBox.ItemsSource = Cats;           
        }


 //This is what's gonna happen each time the ImChecked propierty in a cat changes
 private void CatChanged(bool catIsChecked)
        {
            //Create a empty collection to add the cats that are not checked
            ObservableCollection<Cat> catsToKeep = new ObservableCollection<Cat>();

            //Grab the ones not checked
            for (int i = 0; i < YourComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Cat currentCat = YourComboBox.Items[i] as Cat;

                if (currentCat.ImChecked == false)
                {
                    catsToKeep.Add(currentCat);
                }
            }
            
            //Give the unchecked cats to the comboBox again
            YourComboBox.ItemsSource = catsToKeep;
        }
```

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="YourComboBox"
                      Height="30"
                      Width="150">
                
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ImChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding tb_Name}"/>
                        </CheckBox>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much <3